# How to make a Joomla module installation from a module already installed on another page

Tags: module, plugin, custom-module, custom-component, module-style

I'm working on a new website and I wanted to install a module that I have on another website that I'm administrating (I didn't make that website and the developer who made it, made that module himself). So how could I make an installation for that module and install it on my other page?

NOTE: I have contacted that developer and he said he didn't have that installation anymore, but that I'm permitted to use all the code and files that I wrote to make the same module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "module", I'm going to assume you definitely mean "module", as a lot of people get confused with the different extension types.

Firstly, go to the following directory:

> ROOT/modules/my_module

where `my_module` is the name of the module that you want to take a copy of. Select everything inside this directory and download it.

Then, there will be an XML file which you need to open in any text editor. If you see a tag called `<languages>` or `<media>`, you will also need to download the contents from the following directories:

> ROOT/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_my_module.ini
>
> ROOT/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_my_module.sys.ini

and

> ROOT/media/my_module

Zip everything up and install it on your new site.

If you're having issues installing it, please provide the contents of the XML file and I will update my answer with the correct module directory structure you'll require.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and I'll let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: @TheAdnan - Glad it helped :)